# Google Calendar API - Getting events with Service Account stop working

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

Since Monday 19th of September the application we did with a service account to retrieve all events from a calendar in a different account stop working with no reason.  The service account is under the company domain manage by Google for Work. We are trying to access a `CalendarId` managed by another user and showing them in our website using the server side library `Google.Apis.Calendar.*` in .Net. It continues working well since a period of almost 2 month and suddenly stop working showing this [NOT_FOUND error --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVAhp.png] when executes the request (`request.Execute();`).

```
public class GCalendarService : Service
{

    public GCalendarService(X509Certificate2 certificate, String accountName, String appName) : base(certificate, accountName, appName)
    {
        this.Scopes = new string[] {
            CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, // Manage your calendars
            CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly // View your Calendars
        };
        this.InitializeCredential(certificate);
        this.GService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = this.Credential,
            ApplicationName = appName
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all the events based on a period of time
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="calendarId">The ID of the calendar to get the events</param>
    /// <param name="minDate">The minimun date to request</param>
    /// <param name="maxDate">The max date to request</param>
    /// <param name="maxEvents">The max amount of events to retrieve</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Object GetEvents(string calendarId, DateTime? minDate, DateTime? maxDate, int maxEvents) 
    {
        EventsResource.ListRequest request = ((CalendarService)this.GService).Events.List(calendarId);
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request.ShowDeleted = false;
        request.SingleEvents = true;
        request.MaxResults = maxEvents;
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
        return request.Execute();
    }
```

Is there some update in the Apps Admin for Domain accounts, some new configuration made from google side? because we haven't change anything.
This are some of the test we did:

1. Create new calendar with the company email(make this with different company emails) and share calendar with the "view details" permission with the service account --> DIDNT WORK
2. Create new calendar with my personal gmail account and share calendar with the "view details" permission with the service account --> WORKED
3. Share primary or default account calendar with the "view details" permission with the service account --> WORKED

IMPORTANT: THE CALENDAR ID IS CORRECT, THE SERVICE ACCOUNT CREDENTIALS AND THE CALENDAR PERMISSION ARE TOO, I already prove it and it does get events form the calendar id in the 'TRY IT' helper google have in the developer site to access their endpoint.  also any account in the domain has access to this calendar. [Here is a screenshot of the calendar share settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRUNT.png). Also we have tried creating new service accounts and new calendars. 
If someone have any idea I would be so much grateful, I would really appreciate it, I have done a lot of research a nothing seems to be the solution.

Comment: So, you tested the service account on the API explorer and it retrieves the events, but not on your implementation? Are there any logs you can share aside from the 404 response?

Comment: @adjuremods exactly! it is only happening inside the domain, and yeah with the API explorer and any companyname account we can retrieves the events, but you cannot try the API explorer with a service account. Still if we retrieves all calendars shared with the service account it brings all the calendar shared but the calendar we need it doesnt, even though it is shared the same way no difference.
The console developer of google doesnt show any error, and on Visual Studio only give me this 404 not so util error :/